# Is there any npm module or library for React JS that scan QR and return scan results as masking type, error code, version no, encoding type?

Tags: reactjs

While scanning QR codes, i need to result data like QR text, masking type, encoding code, error code, version number, etc. in a ReactJS web application. Is there any npm module or scanning library for such a type of response after scanning a QR code?

Please suggest any ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any specific library that does exactly that, but you might be able to use the jsQR library.
or

I found this npm module, maybe it is helpful:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode-reader

or try this

```
You could use the <code>qrcode</code> package, which is compatible with React:
<code>var QRCode = require('qrcode');

QRCode.toDataURL('I am a pony!', function (err, url) {
  console.log(url);
})
</code>
This will generate an image URL with your QR code.
``
```

Comment: Thanks for response.... But above npm and library not getting result as i expect. Like If i have QR code and i scan using any npm or QR scan library then i want result parameter like QR text, QR Version Number, QR Error Code, QR Masking Type, QR encoding Type etc.